# How to change the css of an element with the background of a element which is continuously changing after some time intervals?

Tags: jquery

I have used below code for changing the background continuously at some time intervals of body of a HTML page:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
    var images = ["images/bg-a.jpg", "images/bg-b.jpg", "images/bg-c.jpg"];
    var currentImage = 0;

    function changeBackground() {
        $('#bdy').css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[++currentImage] + ')'
        });
        if (currentImage >= images.length - 1) {
            currentImage -= images.length;
        }
    }
    setInterval(changeBackground, 5000);
 });
```

Here "bdy " is id of body.
now i have three span elements in this body as:

```
        <span class="controller" id="bg-a"></span>
        <span class="controller" id="bg-b"></span>
        <span class="controller" id="bg-c"></span>
```

now i want such as if the background of body "is bg-a.jpg" then the css of the span having id="bg-a" should be changed and if if the background of body "is bg-b.jpg" then the css of the span having id="bg-b" should be changed and same as for span having id="bg-c". How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one possible sollution:

http://jsfiddle.net/M3YL3/

```
jQuery(function ($) {
 var images = [
     {url: 'http://placekitten.com/200/302', id: 'bg-a', color: '#ffff00'},
     {url: 'http://placekitten.com/200/303', id: 'bg-b', color: '#ff00ff'},
     {url: 'http://placekitten.com/200/304', id: 'bg-c', color: '#ff0000'}
 ];
 var currentImage = 0;

 function changeBackground() {
     $('#bdy').css({
         backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[++currentImage].url + ')'
     });
     $('#' + images[currentImage].id).css({'background-color': images[currentImage].color});
     if (currentImage >= images.length - 1) {
         currentImage -= images.length;
     }
 }

 setInterval(changeBackground, 5000);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want.

```
function changeBackground() {
    $( '#bdy' ).css( { backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ ++currentImage ] + ')' } );
    if ( currentImage >= images.length - 1 ) {
        currentImage -= images.length;
    }
    var id = $('body').css('background-image');
    id = $('body').css('background-image');
    id = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf('/')+1,id.lastIndexOf('.'));
    $('span#'+id).css({...apply your css...});
}
```